# If I code in php and give specific time to execute by if -else . so will it be executed at a particular time. if the file is kept untouched

Tags: php, hosting, web-hosting

I made a code in php and gave a time of 12pm and want that code to be executed daily at that specific time so will it be executed? if this file is kept untouched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is Resolved. I used cron job for the same

Answer (score 0):

cPanel may or may not allow you to use cron. If your host doesnt provide it you rely on visitors triggering a piece of code that checks the tme and executes if time()>=12pm. If visitors are few you need to run it manually (perhaps by visiting and triggering as aforesaid). (cPanel is commonly used interface for managing linux-apache-mysql-php setups. refer to the interface provided by your host for cron)